# Upgrading from Springboot 2.1.4.RELEASE to 2.5.0 giving IllegalArgumentException on runtime

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, java-8

I upgraded springboot2.1.4.RELEASE to 2.5.0 ,In local, it is able to run fine and read from the application.properties file, but when I try to deploy in aws ECS it is giving the following error. Any pointers will help

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cloudPlatformSecuirtyResourceServerConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'uaaResourceInfo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'UAAResourceInfoConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'moa.aws.secrets.uaa.clientId' in value "${moa.aws.secrets.uaa.clientId}"
```

The application.yml

```
uaa:
 accessTokenURI: ${uaa.accessTokenURI}
 clientId: ${moa.aws.secrets.uaa.clientId}
 clientSecret: ${moa.aws.secrets.uaa.clientSecret}
 clientScope: oa.ups.reader,uaa.resource
```

The code which is calling the bean

```
@Configuration
@Profile({"security"})
public class UAAResourceInfoConfig {

    @Value("${uaa.accessTokenURI}")
    private String uaaAccessTokenURI;

    @Value("${uaa.clientId}")
    private String uaaClientId;

    @Value("${uaa.clientSecret}")
    private String uaaClientSecret;

    @Value("${uaa.clientScope}")
    private String uaaClientScope;

    @Bean("UAAResourceInfo")
    public UAAResourceInfo uaaResourceInfo() {
        return new UAAResourceInfo(uaaAccessTokenURI, uaaClientId, uaaClientSecret, uaaClientScope);
    }
}
```

The only difference between application.properties file and Secrets Manager of aws is , in the properties file the properties are stored individually like

```
moa.aws.secrets.uaa.clientId=xxx
moa.aws.secrets.uaa.clientSecret=xxxx
moa.aws.secrets.moa.db_url=xxxxx
moa.aws.secrets.moa.db_username=xxxx
moa.aws.secrets.moa.db_password=xxxx
```

But in Secrets Manager, they may be stored in a json format

```
moa.aws.secrets={"tenantId": "xxxxx","moa.db_url": "xxxx","moa.db_username": "xxx","moa.db_password": "YOUR_LOCAL_DB_PASS","uaa.clientId": "xxxxxx","uaa.clientSecret": "xxxxx","uaa.scope": "xxxx"}
```

Comment: How is `moa.aws.secrets.uaa.clientId` supplied to your application locally, and how in ECS?

Comment: In application.properties , its pretty simple -moa.aws.secrets.uaa.clientId=xxxxx, but in ECS it is setup as an environment variable something like this in deployment.config file  "secrets": [    {
        "name": "moa.aws.secrets",
        "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:secret:xxxxxxx"
    }],

Comment: They are saved in Secrets Manager of aws