# Upgrading from Springboot 2.1.4.Release to 2.5.0 is giving Illegal Runtime Exception on aws ECS deployment

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, gradle

I have upgraded our app from springboot 2.1.4.Release to 2.5.0 and updated relevant jars for running the application. But when I am trying to deploy and run the app in aws ECS , it is giving the following error.
But when I deploy the earlier commit it is able to deploy fine.
It is not able to read the aws Secrets manager to read the values from there.
On looking carefully, I found theres a difference in startup of the springboot. If anyone can point in the right direction, it will be of great help.

The error in the aws ECS logs:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cloudPlatformSecuirtyResourceServerConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'uaaResourceInfo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'UAAResourceInfoConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'moa.aws.secrets.uaa.clientId' in value "${moa.aws.secrets.uaa.clientId}"
```

The **failed** startup log for the springboot is:

```
2021-08-24T18:24:42.232-04:00

' |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /

2021-08-24T18:24:42.232-04:00

=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

2021-08-24T18:24:42.236-04:00

:: Spring Boot :: (v2.5.0)

2021-08-24T18:24:42.854-04:00

2021-08-24 22:24:42 [main] INFO c.g.d.o.m.MoaApplication.logStarting - Starting MoaApplication using Java 1.8.0_212 on ip-10-228-213-136.ec2.internal with PID 1 (/app/bin/app.jar started by appuser in /app/bin)

2021-08-24T18:24:42.855-04:00

2021-08-24 22:24:42 [main] INFO c.g.d.o.m.MoaApplication.logStartupProfileInfo - The following profiles are active: aws,security

2021-08-24T18:24:50.749-04:00

2021-08-24 22:24:50 [main] INFO o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.

2021-08-24T18:24:52.715-04:00

2021-08-24 22:24:52 [main] INFO o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1900 ms. Found 29 JPA repository interfaces.

2021-08-24T18:24:53.919-04:00

2021-08-24 22:24:53 [main] INFO o.s.c.c.s.GenericScope.setSerializationId - BeanFactory id=ac4ea7b8-8e46-3560-bd24-f258beed7bb3

2021-08-24T18:24:54.857-04:00

2021-08-24 22:24:54 [main] INFO o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization - Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

2021-08-24T18:24:54.860-04:00

2021-08-24 22:24:54 [main] INFO o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization - Bean 'stringOrNumberMigrationVersionConverter' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$StringOrNumberToMigrationVersionConverter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

2021-08-24T18:24:54.914-04:00

2021-08-24 22:24:54 [main] INFO o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization - Bean 'management.metrics-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MetricsProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MetricsProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

2021-08-24T18:24:54.915-04:00

2021-08-24 22:24:54 [main] INFO o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization - Bean 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.data.RepositoryMetricsAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.data.RepositoryMetricsAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

The startup log for the **successful** deployment is

[image]

The only difference I can see between the successful deployment and failed deployment is, the container is loading and initializing the **PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration** bean by itself for successful deployment

This is linked to the same question asked by me in this post but didnt get any resposne
[Upgrading from Springboot 2.1.4.RELEASE to 2.5.0 giving IllegalArgumentException on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68839966/upgrading-from-springboot-2-1-4-release-to-2-5-0-giving-illegalargumentexception)

Below is the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.5.0'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://xxxxxx/ARJLY"
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
            name = "xxxxxxx"
        }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        //docker
        classpath('se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'distribution'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'docker'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

group = 'com.ge.digital.oa.moa'
archivesBaseName = 'moa-svc'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '6.8'
}

//dependencyManagement {
//  imports {
//      mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws:2.0.1.RELEASE'
//  }
//}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    add buildscript.repositories.getByName("oa-publish-repo")
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
}

mainClassName = "com.ge.digital.oa.moa.MoaApplication"

eclipse {
    classpath {
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

sourceSets {
    generated
}

sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/generated']

configurations{
    querydslapt
}

dependencies {

    implementation('com.ge.digital.oa.common:oa-common:3.0.0') {
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
        exclude group: 'io.micrometer', module: 'micrometer-core'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.hateoas', module: 'spring-hateoas'
        //exclude group: 'org.springframework.cloud', module: 'spring-cloud-context'        
    }

    //implementation('org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client')
    implementation('org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.5.0')

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')

    implementation('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3');
    implementation('commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4')

    implementation("com.h2database:h2")
    implementation('org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.13')

    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok')

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')

    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")

    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

    implementation('com.opencsv:opencsv:5.5')

    compile ("org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.5")

    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-core:4.2.1")
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:4.2.1")
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1:jpa")

    annotationProcessor(
            "javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api",
            "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1:jpa"

    )
    
    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:5.4.31.Final")
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vladmihalcea/hibernate-types-52
    implementation group: 'com.vladmihalcea', name: 'hibernate-types-52', version: '2.10.3'
    
    //OSS Scan fix
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: '2.5.0'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-context
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-context', version: '3.0.0'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.7'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on
    implementation group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk15on', version: '1.64'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '30.0-jre'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2
    //implementation group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2', version: '2.3.6.RELEASE'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.12.0'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config', version: '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager', version: '1.11.355'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies
    //runtimeOnly group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-dependencies', version: '2020.0.3', ext: 'pom'
```

---

Update:
As suggested, I tried this option in application.yml too..but to no success

---

```
spring:
  config:    
    activate:
      on-profile: aws
    use-legacy-processing: true
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

Comment: You have a very specific error message: You aren't providing an expected property. (Based on the `@Value`, probably one that you required yourself.)

Comment: Yes...it should read it from aws secrets manager..in local I am giving the value in application.properties but in aws ECS it should resolve that path in application.yml and read from the secrets manager